# Ошибка js в drupal7

Tags: jquery, drupal

Ошибка js в админке представления
в консоли ругается на файл sites/all/modules/views/js/views-admin.js
и пишет: Uncaught TypeError: $form.once is not a function

функции требующие jquery не работают.. не нажимаются кнопки..
прилагаю скриншот..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал разные версии jquery через модуль jquery_update, пробовал вообще его удалить, используя jquery v 1.4 из ядра
переустанавливал модуль views.
- ничего не меняется, все та же ошибка..

в исходном коде страницы смотрел - сначала первым делом подключается jquery, а уже потом остальные файлы.

что за ошибка, как от нее избавиться?
куда рыть? что еще сделать?

вроде это ошибка не модуля views.. в чем-то другом косяк.. не могу понять в чем и как найти..

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему таким образом:
начал поочередно вырубать модули и  смотреть не изменилось ли чего с проблемой.

в итоге определил что после выключения модуля **js_injector** всё работает.
какойто косяк в нем..